# Is there anything like Environment.SpecialFolder but for registry paths

Tags: c#, .net, registry

I want to store some app information in the registry and I'm not sure where should I store it. I want the info to be for all users so I wouldn't use HKEY_CURRENT_USER. Maybe HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE but then I'm not sure where in there. I don't know what are the standards for this and something like `Environment.SpecialFolder` but for registry paths or folders would be a lot safer and more elegant.

Comment: Are you sure you want the registry and not `Environment.SpecialFolder.CommonApplicationData`?

Comment: I'm sure. I'm actually using both.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No -- unlike the filesystem, there's no need for such a method because the registry has somewhat standardized locations where things go.

You should store your data in a key following this format:

`HKEY_HIVE\SOFTWARE\Publisher\Program`

for example:

`HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows`

If you need data to be global to the entire machine, put your things inside `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE`, but note that writing to this location will require administrative rights unless you modify the DACLs on your key to behave differently (in some form of installer or something like that).

If you're storing per-user data (**hint** -- most data is per user), then you should put things in `HKEY_CURRENT_USER`, which has the advantage that no special rights are required for that user to access their hive (by default).

Comment: +1 For mentioning the administrative rights required for HKLM, as a side note, on some systems they are locked down that a standard user can't modify HKCU as well (this is rare, but I have seen it in a Citrix environment)

Comment: I think I'll just use the current user; don't want to annoy the heck out of my users. Very clarifying answer.

Answer (score 7):

Check the [Microsoft.Win32.Registry](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.win32.registry%28v=VS.80%29.aspx) object. There you can find some objects representing common registry paths, such as:

- CurrentUser
- LocalMachine
- ClassesRoot
- Users
- PerformanceData
- CurrentConfig
- DynData

For example, if you want to access HKEY_CURRENT_USER:

```
Microsoft.Win32.RegistryKey key;
key = Microsoft.Win32.Registry.CurrentUser.CreateSubKey("Names");
key.SetValue("Name", "Isabella");
key.Close();
```

Comment: I don't think he's looking for *how* to access the registry, he's looking for where in the registry he should place his data.

Comment: Actually this is quite close to what I was looking for. It looks better than writing the registry key (up to my own created keys) with string literals if nothing else.

Comment: Yes, but he's looking for the equivalent way to refer registry paths, such as the equivalent of `Environment.SpecialFolder` in directories.

Comment: @jsoldi: Fair enough :) +1 to this answer then. @Daniel: True, but one shouldn't just randomly try to place things under any of those keys -- one should follow the format specified in either of the two other answers here. (EDIT: Well, I guess my answer because the other one got deleted by it's author)